# SQL Server stored procedure: delete record dynamically

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

I need to delete (read/update) some values in some tables, and would like to use a stored procedure to reduce security issues.

Since tables are many and records even more and it is not reasonable to write a stored procedure for each combination, and since everybody has this kind of need, I thought could have been easy to find a stored procedure to do this.. but googling a lot I did not find a simple and short answer, so I tried to build my own stored procedure. But I'm afraid it could have some security issues: principally when I declare `@Table` as `nvarchar(30)`.. I tried to declare as TABLE but it returns error..

Can suggest what is not acceptable and suggest a solution?

Thanks

Here the stored procedure for deleting.. but for other action could be similar:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spDeleteRecord
(
    @UID        nvarchar(20) = NOT NULL,
    @PWD        nvarchar(30) = NOT NULL,
    @Table      sysname,
    @WhereField sysname,
    @WhereValue nvarchar(150) = NOT NULL
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @S nvarchar(max) = '',
            @P nvarchar(max) = ''

    SET @S = 'DELETE t
              from dbo.'+quotename(@Table)+' t 
              join dbo.subUsers su on t.UID = su.UID 
              where ' + quotename(@WhereField) + ' = @_WhereValue 
                and su.SUID = @_UID 
                and su.PWD = @_PWD'    

   SET @P = '@_UID nvarchar(50),
             @_PWD nvarchar(50),
             @_Table sysname,
             @_WhereField sysname,
             @_WhereValue nvarchar(150)'

   --PRINT @S
   EXEC sp_executesql @S, @P, @UID, @PWD, @Table, @WhereField, @WhereValue

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Thanks for reading
Joe

Comment: a dynamic proc to delete rows...what could possibly go wrong!

Comment: Why this code? Why not use `CASCADE DELETE` in the foreign keys, or a TRIGGER that deletes related records? It's not only the *security* issues. Unless you call *all* deletes inside a single procedure, you'll have zombie entries. Why not write *one* stored procedure to delete all related entries? You could even use code generation to create the delete statements

Comment: well, these are simple tables without related records..Basically are table containing the name of the user that activated a certain service
and the user modify its own subscription.
in any case.. never used `CASCADE DELETE` but it could be useful in other situation.
Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do it like this:

```
SET @S = 'DELETE t
          from dbo.'+quotename(@Table)+' t 
          join dbo.subUsers su on t.UID = su.UID 
          where ' + quotename(@WhereField) + ' = @_WhereValue 
            and su.SUID = @_UID 
            and su.PWD = @_PWD'    

SET @P = '@_UID nvarchar(50),
         @_PWD nvarchar(50),
         @_WhereValue nvarchar(150)'

--PRINT @S
EXEC sp_executesql @S, @P, @_WhereValue = @WhereValue, @_UID = @UID, @_PWD = @PWD
```

Basically, the parameter list can only refer to parameters that are actually embedded in the SQL string.

Also, note that `@Table` and `@WhereField` would be more correct as datatype `sysname`.  I would also probably have restricted `@UID`, `@PWD`, and `@WhereValue` to `NOT NULL` because I hate unhandled nulls.

However, you really need to consider if you want to do this.  To me this feels like leaving a loaded gun lying around.  What happens when you call this with a table that happens to have a `UID` field that happens to coincide to the values in the `dbo.subUsers` table even though no relation exists there?  I don't see any significant advantage of this method over just running the parameterized query from your application, and the fact that the query changes between executions means that you may run into problems with parameter sniffing so you may end up with suboptimal execution plans.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. well yes.. `NOT NULL` in input fields, then.. what is difference to write `@_WhereValue = @WhereValue, @_UID = @UID, @_PWD = @PWD` in EXEC instead of simply , @WhereValue, @UID, @PWD?


since table foreseen to be modified with this sproc are some 12 only, could help mitigate risks checking if `@Table` is included in the list?

My fear is just to leave a loaded gun to a child.. but other solution can be to write 12 sproc with `TableName` already set..

Or I'm not considering something?

thanks

Comment: @Joe Well, it's not just that I changed it to `@_WhereValue = @WhereValue, @_UID = @UID, @_PWD = @PWD`, it's that I eliminated `@Table` and `@WhereField` from the list of parameters.  A fixed set of known tables certainly helps with the risky part, but in the end you're still back to the point of "What does this add?  Why is this easier when you're giving up the flexibility of writing the query?  Why not a function in the application where you can specify enumerations and validate the query some?"  I'm not saying it's not wrong to do it the way you are, but some might.  It's kind of weird.